# office-js: using JS excel api as front end Data Table

Tags: excel, office-js, office-js-helpers

Is it possible to run js excel api in my web application using data from my server. I want to use this api as a replacement of html data table. 
Need a step by step guide if possible and what are the T&C for any commercial use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Office JavaScript APIs contain objects and members for building add-ins and interacting with Office content and web services. it extending and interacting office clients.

In your scenario, I think you could use [Excel Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0), You can use Microsoft Graph to allow your web application to read and modify Excel workbooks stored in OneDrive for Business, SharePoint site.